# sql statement to select value from a table where that table's name is from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a master list, with columns `userID`, `tableName`. In another schema I have multiple tables with corresponding `tableName`, each of which have the same structure. I'm looking for a query such that when I call it with `userID` as an argument, it looks up the relevant tableName from master table, then modifies a certain column in that table.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL for this.  Table names cannot be parameterized otherwise.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION schname.funcname(_userid integer)
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE vartab TEXT;
DECLARE count_var INTEGER;
BEGIN

  SELECT tableName FROM table1
  WHERE userID = $1 INTO vartab;

  EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE otherschema.%I SET some_col = some_val WHERE some_cond', vartab);
  GET DIAGNOSTICS count_var = ROW_COUNT;

  RETURN count_var;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: about dynamic SQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN